# startActivity() is not working inside BroadcastReceiverclass

Tags: android

My code is :

```
Intent lockintent = new Intent();         
lockintent.setClassName("com.example.lalitha.s1",
                         "com.example.lalitha.s1.WipeActivity");
context.startActivity(lockintent);
mDPM = DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(                                      Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(context, DeviceAdminSample .class);
boolean active = mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdmin);
   if (active) {
        mDPM.lockNow();
    }
   else{
       Toast.makeText(context, "not locked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

that `context.startActivity` is not getting executed 
if i omit that then its showing device "not locked"

Comment: You starting from Recevier so Add flag to your intent **intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);**

Comment: If you really want to get help, you should learn how to properly ask for it. And that is by providing the information what you intend to do here in the first place, gathering information before asking the question in order to try and solve it by yourself, and if that fails, provide enough information here so that we can get an idea what it is you try to do and how to help you. Just adding a code snippet and stating "it doesn't work" won't get you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this bit:

```
Intent lockintent = new Intent();         
lockintent.setClassName("com.example.lalitha.s1",
                     "com.example.lalitha.s1.WipeActivity");
```

with

```
Intent lockintent = new Intent(context, WipeActivity.class);
lockintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

But bear in mind that the Toast message will still be shown.